# replacing repeated strings using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string as follows:

```
text <- "http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/jpg.png"
```

I want to eliminate all duplicated addresses, so my expected result is:

```
expected <- "http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/jpg.png"
```

I tried `(^[\w|.|:|\/]*),\1+` in regex101.com and it works removing the first repetition of the string (fails at the second). However, if I port it to R's `gsub` it doesn't work as expected:

```
gsub("(^[\\w|.|:|\\/]*),\\1+", "\\1", text)
```

I've tried with `perl = FALSE` and `TRUE` to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are these duplicates sequential, or out-of-order ?

Comment: Always sequential

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are sequential, you just need to modify your regex slightly.

Take out your BOS anchor `^`.
Add a cluster group around the comma and backreference, then quantify it `(?:,\1)+`.
And, lose the pipe symbol `|` as in a class it's just a literal.

`([\w.:/]+)(?:,\1)+`

https://regex101.com/r/FDzop9/1

```
 ( [\w.:/]+ )         # (1), The adress
 (?:                  # Cluster
      , \1                 # Comma followed by what found in group 1 
 )+                   # Cluster end, 1 to many times
```

Note - if you use split and unique then combine, you will lose the ordering of 
the items.

Comment: I can only see 2 distinct items in the text

Comment: yep all good. And this in R code is `gsub(pattern = "([\\w.:/]+)(?:,\\1)+", "\\1", text, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Not sure in what conditions you'd lose the ordering if using split/unique/combine... @SymbolixAU's answer seems to retain the original order (tested with a few variations).

Comment: @DominicComtois - Oh, I'm not sure that unique doesn't require a sorted list to test for uniqueness. Otherwise, it would be a tremendous time penalty for say 100,000 items. After sorting, I'd guess the original ordering is forever lost.

Comment: @DominicComtois - Oh sure. I don't really know what the `R` language is written in. I'm going by [C++ definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). It could be they roll their own with a really poor implementation, taking like 40 minutes (to forever) to unique 100,000 lines by not using sort.

Comment: If anyone's interested it's [written in `c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/unique.c)

Comment: @SymbolixAU - I guess you could do it without sorting, but it would take a lot more time.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to split the string on the comma, then unique the results, then re-combine for your single text

```
paste0(unique(strsplit(text, ",")[[1]]), collapse = ",")
# [1] "http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/jpg.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text <- c("http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/jpg.png",
          "http://q.co/imag/qrs.png,http://q.co/imag/qrs.png")
df <- data.frame(no = 1:2, text)
```

You can use functions from `tidyverse` if your strings are in a dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(df, text, sep = ",") %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  group_by(no) %>% 
  mutate(text = paste(text, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

The output is:

```
#     no                                              text
#   <int>                                             <chr>
# 1     1 http://x.co/imag/xyz.png,http://x.co/imag/jpg.png
# 2     2                          http://q.co/imag/qrs.png
```